# Button not wrapping around content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a button like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_down"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    />
```

But the button isn't wrapping the content:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M07UR.png

Notice the massive amount of space to the right of the (faded) icon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For design and usability reasons, I think there's a default `minWidth` associated with  the button. Add `android:minWidth="1dp"` and the button is going to be as wide as your text.